# Mobile news reader

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm using C# and probably .Net compact framework. How should I design mobile news reader (RSS, Atom...).

What are risks I should be aware before I start? 
What libraries are there to help me read and parse data and synchronize it when going from offline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the OpenNetCF library that contains the class `OpenNETCF.Rss`, but it's a commercial product though:

http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/e74e8115-1f33-72d9-a221-8a92e072e3d6.htm

I've never used it so I can't say anything about the quality etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use C# for writing an application for WIndows Mobile, you've got two choices:

- Use .NET Compact Framework (Windows Mobile 5-6)
- Use Silverlight (Windows Phone 7)

Keep in mind that WP7 applications are not backwards compatible and that WM5/6 apps will not work on WP7.

Reading and parsing the data is easy. There are a lot of [examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919073854/http://geekswithblogs.net/jwhitehorn/archive/2007/06/26/113488.aspx) out there to parse either one or several common formats (rss, Atom)
[WP7 has built in support](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/faq.html).

Further, I don't really understand what you mean with risks and synchronization?
When you're offline you're simply unable to retrieve the data. Besides that there's only one-way synchronization since you can only read feeds and not change.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Yakhnin has [a sample on his blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20090801002816/http://blog.opennetcf.com:80/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,70c9a4c0-57e2-45fe-b106-941250744266.aspx).